# SDL2 at the end of resizing event

Tags: c, sdl-2

I'm trying to find a way to fire an event only at the end of resizing event in SDL-2.

both polling on sdl events using `SDL_PollEvent` and `SDL_SetEventFilter` fire on the resizing event itself not at the end.

**EDIT**

Platform: linux

Display server: X11

Comment: How do you catch resizing events? In my case both `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED` and `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED` are generated at the end of resizing.

Comment: Related? [Getting Continuous Window Resize Event in SDL 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32294913/getting-continuous-window-resize-event-in-sdl-2)

Comment: I tried this solution and it only fire at the start not at the end

Comment: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowEvent example code for `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED` says  that the event occurs _after_ the event

Comment: within the resizing event if you stop the cursor from moving it will fire `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_RESIZED` even before the resizing event end totally